# dockerfile - add a package to ubi minimal base image from private repository

Tags: docker, dockerfile, redhat, rhel, ubi

I am trying to build my docker image from nodejs minimal as base image.
nodejs minimal does not have shadow-utils which I need to add user group and user.
The nodejs minimal image I am using is hosted in a private repository and this repo does not host the shadow-utils package.
How do I install shadow-utils in the nodejs minimal image via my dockerfile?
I have tried the following in my dockerfile

```
FROM private.repo.com/node:20.9.0_ubi9

RUN microdnf install shadow-utils -y && \
    microdnf clean all
```

When I run `docker build -t myimage:mytag .` it fails saying the following. Not sure if this is a permission issue or a repository issue.

```
 => ERROR [6/7] RUN microdnf install shadow-utils -y && microdnf clean all            0.4s
------
 > [6/7] RUN microdnf install shadow-utils -y && microdnf clean all:
0.289 error: Failed to create: /var/cache/yum/metadata
------
dockerfile:10
--------------------
   9 |     
  10 | >>> RUN microdnf install shadow-utils -y && \
  11 | >>> microdnf clean all
  12 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c microdnf install shadow-utils -y && microdnf clean all" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

it could be a permission issue. Please try this and check:

```
FROM private.repo.com/node:20.9.0_ubi9

# set permissions
RUN mkdir -p /var/cache/yum && \
    chown root:root /var/cache/yum && \
    chmod 755 /var/cache/yum

RUN microdnf install shadow-utils -y && \
    microdnf clean all
```